# Django - How to loop xml tag in xml

Tags: python, xml, django, elementtree

i want to save/update my xml file from my html form. There were a few option that i have to key in many data for one attribute. But i don't know how to loop the data when to save it in xml.

For example, i want to save the attributes like this

```
<keywords>
     <string>WFS</string>
     <string>WMS</string>
     <string>GEOSERVER</string>
</keywords>
```

but when i hit submit button the result was like this

```
<keywords>
    <string>WFS WMS GEOSERVER</string>
</keywords>
```

By the way, i'm using ElementTree

Answer (score 0):

you can do it [this way](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents):

```
keywords = ET.Element('keywords')
for string_ in strings: # < -- your strings
    string = ET.SubElement(keywords, 'string')
    string.text = string_

ET.dump(keywords)
```

**Tested**:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> keywords = ET.Element('keywords')
>>> strings = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for string_ in strings:
        string = ET.SubElement(keywords, 'string')
        string.text = string_

>>> ET.dump(keywords)
<keywords><string>a</string><string>b</string><string>c</string></keywords>
>>>
```